# Change Spectre.Console mask character for secure input

Tags: c#, .net, console, data-masking, spectre.console

I'm using the Spectre.Console library's [password feature](https://spectreconsole.net/prompts/text#secrets). It echos asterisks (***) instead of the secret text.

Is it possible to change the mask character, or to disable it completely (sudo style)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, once the property `IsSecret` is set via `Secret()` language extension method and the prompt is shown as shown below `ShowAsync` is executed which there is nothing to do what you are asking.

```
public static string AskPassword()
{
    return AnsiConsole.Prompt(
        new TextPrompt<string>("[thistle1]Password[/]?")
            .PromptStyle("grey50")
            .Secret());
}
```

See also source [method](https://github.com/spectreconsole/spectre.console/blob/main/src/Spectre.Console/Prompts/TextPrompt.cs#L104:L174)